# How do i check the valid association and the related model existence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am  following this pattern

`it { is_expected.to respond_to(:cars) }` for checking the association

Now accidentally in the model, let's assume I have this line

`has_many :bars`

So in the test, after seeing the model. I went ahead and did this

`it { is_expected.to respond_to(:bars) }`

And the test passes, but there is no model `Bar` how do we rectify this.

Comment: Not a direct answer but look into `Shoulda` gem. It make association testing as easy as `should have_many(: bars)`

Comment: @Sharj Yes, it's checking for Bar model. But I don't want to introduce one more dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer in a few parts. First, you can help avoid these typos of errors by test-driving your implementation. If you write a failing test first, the error message is another opportunity for you to recognize the typo: "Wait, a minute... it doesn't make sense for this to respond to `bars`. That's not what I meant..."

The larger answer is that this test on its own has so little value as to be worthless. If you make the typo above in both the implementation and that test and *no other test fails* then it's hard for me to believe it matters at all if the object response to `cars`, `bars` or any other typo.

A more valuable test would exercise the behavior of the association. For instance, if you wanted to test that a `Person` could associate a `Car` to their user, you could start with a feature test that exercises that feature. The test failure would guide you toward a working implementation that may or may not require that association. But if you typo the association you will find out because you are testing actual behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`has_many :bars` adds many methods to your model, `bars` is one of them, and `respond_to` matcher just check if there's such publicly available method - so you don't really testing what you think you would like to test.

You could for example do something like this:

```
expect(subject.bars.build).to be_instance_of(Bar)
```

This spec would fail if `Bar` does not exist.

I'm also pretty sure that

```
expect(subject.bars).to eq []
```

Would fail too, since it should try to find those in the DB, and missing model would surface here as well.

Also this

```
expect{ subject.bars.build }.not_to raise_exception
```

should also fail.

That's generally the problem with dynamic languages - errors (including typos) are not immediately caught.

I actually didn't know that you can define a relation to unexisting model. But it makes sense - checking if the classes exists during the class definition could be a bit too heavy.

Comment: Thanks so much, totally makes sense